# Logo and navbar alignment issues in Wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment

I need help in writing a css fix for aligning the logo and navbar in desktop and mobile responsive modes. No options available in customize menu. Thanks in advance. 
[My Site](https://buywiseanz.com/) 
[Theme Used](https://themegrilldemos.com/spacious-store/) 
[Problem SS1](https://i.snipboard.io/YBwetL.jpg) 
[Problem SS2](https://i.snipboard.io/fQE0q3.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, this site has rules on the way to ask questions, and as a new user, you should read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, you are expected to show your research. It will aid others to better understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use [Display flex CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Example your website:

```
<div id="header-text-nav-wrap">
    <div id="header-left-section">
        <!-- your logo here -->
    </div>
    <div id="header-right-section">
        <!-- your menu -->
        <!-- your searh and other -->
    </div>
</div>

<style> 
    #header-text-nav-wrap{
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    #header-logo-image img{
        max-height: 60px;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center
    }
    #header-right-section{
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
    }
    .main-navigation,
    .header-action{
        padding-top: 0; 
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .better-responsive-menu #header-text-nav-wrap{
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .better-responsive-menu #header-logo-image {
            float: none;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }   
        .better-responsive-menu #header-right-section {
            -webkit-box-flex: 1;
            -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
            width: 100%;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
            -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
            -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
            flex-direction: row-reverse;
        }
        #header-right-section .header-action{
            min-width: 200px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Man thank you so much, your code worked flawlessly.